# Category-Theoretic relation between Orbit-Stabilizer and Rank-Nullity Theorems

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

In linear algebra, the Rank-Nullity theorem states that given a vector space $V$ and an $n\times n$ matrix $A$,
$$\text{rank}(A) + \text{null}(A) = n$$
or that
$$\text{dim(image}(A)) + \text{dim(ker}(A)) = \text{dim}(V).$$

---

In abstract algebra, the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem states that given a group $G$ of order $n$, and an element $x$ of the set $G$ acts on,
$$|\text{orb}(x)||\text{stab}(x)| = |G|.$$

---

Other than the visual similarity of the expressions, is there some deeper, perhaps category-theoretic connection between these two theorems? Is there, perhaps, a functor from the category of groups $\text{Grp}$ to some category where linear transformations are morphisms? Am I even using the words functor and morphism correctly in this context?

Comment: I dont know if this is useful, but my first thought was "Take logs".

Comment: I think $\operatorname{orb}$ is very different from $\operatorname{Im}(A)$... One is enlarged by the elements of objects, the others by considering all the morphisms...

Comment: I don't think that category theory has a lot to say about these kind of questions. Indeed, dimension and cardinality are hard to define using purely categorical notions. And "taking an element $x$ of the set $G$ acts on" is also very uncategorical.

Comment: @Mr.T  For $x \in X$, let $\text{eval}_x: G \to X$ be the map $g \mapsto g \cdot x$.  Then the orbit of $x$ is exactly the image of $\text{eval}_x$, and the stabilizer is its "kernel" in a sense.

Comment: It might be more relevant to look at the similarity of the rank theorem $rk(A)+dim(Ker(A))=dim(V)$ for $A$ a linear operator from $V$ to $W$ and the kernel theorem, if $f:G\rightarrow H$ is  a group morphism then $|Ker(f)|\times |Im(f)|=|G|$. The similarity of the theorems is simply given by the fact that all non-empty fibers over $A$ all look a lot like $Ker(A)$, and all non-empty fibers over $f$ all look a lot like $Ker(f)$. With this simple idea (which is also used for the proof of the orbit-stab theorem), formulas are easy to prove and category theory here would be too much IMHO.

Comment: First isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @ClémentGuérin I would appreciate a bit more detail, could you perhaps expand your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments by Clement Guerin and Berci above, the Rank-Nullity Theorem is more properly seen as an immediate consequence of the First Isomorphism Theorem, which says that $\mathrm{Im}(A) \cong V / \mathrm{Ker}(A)$. Taking dimensions of these spaces gives the statement of the Rank-Nullity Theorem, since the "rank" is the dimension of the image of $A$, and the "nullity" is the dimension of the kernel, and the dimension of $V / \mathrm{Ker}(A)$ is just the difference in dimensions $\dim(V) - \dim(\mathrm{Ker}(A))$.

Answer (score 5):

The intuition behind this question is spot-on. I'm going to try to fill out some of the details to make this work.

The first thing to note is that a linear map $A:V\to V$ also gives a genuine group action: it is the additive group of $V$ acting on the set $V$ by addition. That is, any $v\in V$ acts on $x\in V$ as $v: x \mapsto x+Av.$

Now we see that given any $x$ in $V$ the stabilizer subgroup $\text{stab}(x)$ of this action is precisely the kernel of $A.$ The orbit of $x$ is $x$ plus the image of $A.$

If we are working with a vector space over a finite field, we can take the cardinality of these sets as in the formula $|\text{orb}(x)||\text{stab}(x)| = |G|$ and as @Ravi suggests, take the logarithm of this where the base is the size of the field and we get exactly the rank-nullity equation.

If we have an infinite field then this doesn't work and we need to think more along the lines of a *categorified* orbit-stabilizer theorem. In this case, for each $x\in V$ we can find a bijection:

$$
\text{orb}(x) \cong G / \text{stab}(x)
$$

and as @Nick points out, this bijection gives us the First Isomorphism Theorem:
$$
\mathrm{Im}(A) \cong V / \mathrm{Ker}(A).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The orbit-stabilizer formula stems from the fact that, given an action
of $G$ on $X$, the map

$$ G/G_x \ni gG_x \mapsto gx \in Gx $$

is an isomorphism of $G$-sets between the coset space $G/G_x$ and
the orbit $Gx$ of $x \in X$. Here $G$ acts on $G/G_x$ via left
multiplication.

The closest analogy is the case of an $R$-module $M$ where
$R/ann(m) \cong Rm$ for any $m \in M$.